# Тестирование почты на MAMP Pro macOS

Tags: php, sendmail, mamp

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно тестировать исходящую почту на локальном сервере MAMP Pro на macOS? Раньше использовал Windows и там в программе Openserver вся исходящая почта скидывалась в папку. Как можно сделать что то подобное на macOS? Желательно чтобы вся почта помещалась в файл и была доступна в папке для проверки. Либо другой вариант.

Comment: Если у Вас PRO версия, то там есть Postfix

Comment: А как тот PostFix настроить?

Comment: @k0mar У вас случайно нету примера как настроить и где что указывать? Нужно просто тестировать почту

Comment: В целом, в доке все описано https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/Postfix/